# How do I add data into a database using Sqlite manager

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, sqlitemanager

I want execute the insert query the query was working fine when we call this `InsUpdateDelData` its return false then the data was not inserted

```
- (IBAction)addToCart:(id)sender {

    AppDelegate *obj = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] ;
    NSString *insert = @"ahmadyarimran@yahoo.com" ;


    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
    @"INSERT INTO   cart_user(user_id,product_price,product_type,categories_type,product_images,description) values('%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@')",insert,handBegsImages.product_price,handBegsImages.product_tagline,handbegCategoriess.handbegid,handBegsImages.main_image,handBegsImages.product_description];
    BOOL abc = [obj InsUpdateDelData:insertSQL];
     NSLog(@"print the value of abc %@=", abc) ;
    if (abc == TRUE) {
      NSLog(@"@ Data was Inserted");
    }
    else{
          [Utility showAlertView:@"Plz try again message" message:@"Again"  viewcontroller:self];
    }
     }


 -(BOOL)InsUpdateDelData:(NSString*)SqlStr
{
    if([SqlStr isEqual:@""])
        return NO;

    BOOL RetrunValue;
    RetrunValue = NO;
    const char *sql = [SqlStr cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &stmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
        RetrunValue = YES;

    if(RetrunValue == YES)
    {
        if(sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE) {

        }
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    }
    return RetrunValue;
}
```

Comment: the report is  not an error

Comment: NSLog(@"print the sqlite3 value %s =",sqlite3_errmsg(database)) ;
my problem was solve for doing this tnx

Comment: Very good. BTW, you might want to be wary of building SQL statements like this. If any of those string values happened to have an apostrophe in it, your SQL would fail. It's better to use `?` placeholders and then bind values to them. If you do this properly, your code becomes cumbersome quickly, so you might consider something like [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), which has functions like `executeUpdate` and `executeQuery` that take arrays of values, but perform the necessary `sqlite3_bind_text` calls for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `InsUpdateDelData` returned `NO`, then that means that `sqlite3_prepare_v2` did not return `SQLITE_OK`. If you want to know why it did not return `SQLITE_OK`, then log the error immediately after `sqlite3_prepare_v2` failed, but before calling any other SQLite functions:

```
NSLog(@"err=%s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
```